# VBS script to modify a Windows 7 library does not work when elevated

Tags: vbscript, windows-7

Hello everyone and thanks for reading my question.

I have a simple VBS script which copies a Windows 7 library from a storage folder to the Windows Libraries folder and shows it in the Windows Explorer navigation pane.

Here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wsnet, shell, fso, shellapp, objFolder, objFolderItem, verb, username

' Setup variables
Set wsnet    = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set shell    = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shellapp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
username     = UCase(wsnet.Username)

' Remove read only flag from local copy of library
shell.Run ("attrib -R ""C:\Users\" & username & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Books.library-ms"""), 0, True

' Copy library file from storage to local
fso.CopyFile "D:\Home\Seven\Libraries\Books.library-ms", "C:\Users\" & username & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\", Rrue

' Show local library in navigation pane
Set objFolder = shellapp.Namespace("C:\Users\" & username & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Books.library-ms")
For Each verb In objFolderItem.Verbs()
    If Replace(verb.Name, "&", "") = "Show in navigation pane" Then
        verb.DoIt()
    End If
Next
```

Now, when I run the library script above on its own, it works absolutely fine and never reports any errors.

However, I have another VBScript which simply launches the library script.  It runs itself elevated using an elevation function.  Here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim bElevate, shell

' Run logon script with elevated permissions under UAC
bElevate = False
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then If WScript.Arguments(WScript.Arguments.Count-1) <> "|" Then bElevate = True
If bElevate Or WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then ElevateUAC

' Setup variables
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "D:\Home\Seven\Scripts\Logon\buildLibraries.vbs", 0, False

' Run script with elevated privelages (used to ensure logon script runs under UAC)
Sub ElevateUAC
    Dim sParms, oShell
    sParms = " |"
    If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
        For i = WScript.Arguments.Count-1 To 0 Step -1
            sParms = " " & WScript.Arguments(i) & sParms
        Next
    End If
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oShell.ShellExecute "cscript.exe ", "//NoLogo " & WScript.ScriptFullName & sParms, , "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I run the library script from the launcher script, it often (not always) doesn't work properly.  It creates a library TMP file in the Libraries folder so it seems that it starts modifying the library but doesn't finish.

Since it works from a single script, there is clearly some issue with running 2 scripts at the same time that I'm not understanding.

For another example, I just created a batch file containing these two lines:

```
call C:\Windows\System32\cscript /B //NoLogo D:\Home\Seven\Scripts\Logon\logonseven.vbs
call C:\Windows\System32\cscript /B //NoLogo D:\Home\Seven\Scripts\Logon\startmenu.vbs
```

`logonseven.vbs` is the main logon script that does many, many things (thousands of lines).  One of the things it does is it populates the All Programs section of the start menu (not the pinned list, just the all programs menu).

`startmenu.vbs` simply adds a few shortcuts to the pinned list of the Windows 7 start menu using the usual verb method as shown below:

```
Function pin(path, exec)
    Set objFolder = shellapp.Namespace(path)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(exec)
    For Each verb In objFolderItem.Verbs() 
        If Replace(verb.Name, "&", "") = "Pin to Start Menu" Then verb.DoIt()
    Next
End Function
```

`logonseven.vbs` will elevate itself.  `startmenu.vbs` will not be elevated.

When I run both scripts together from the batch file, sometimes the start menu code in `logonseven.vbs` doesn't work properly and not all start menu items in the All Programs menu will populate.

But again, when I combine both scripts into a single script, it works fine.

Not using elevation sometimes fixes the issue but not always and after running the launcher script a few more times, it breaks again.

Comment: What is `D:` you said it's a storage folder, all folders are storage folder so what does that mean?

Comment: It's just a folder on an internal hard drive.  All code is running on an internal hard drive which consists of C: (Windows partition) and D: (storage partition, contains all data).

Comment: Please show us a command line for your second script (with elevation). And since the failing script is `buildLibraries.vbs` it would be nice to see its content also.

Comment: @montonero The first script is the one being called by the second script.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks, that wasn't quite clear to me.

Comment: IMO this is some issue inside of a Windows shell code. I could suggest to split the elevated and non-elevated functionality of your library script and run them separately.

Comment: I have added an edit to my question to test this out.  Suffice to say, using a batch file to run both scripts at the same time (one elevated and one not elevated) doesn't work properly.  Merging both scripts into one script and running that one script works fine though.  Running one script from the other sometimes works, it depends on what the script is doing at the time which I don't understand at all.

Comment: @montonero when you say run them separately, do you mean run them simultaneously or one after the other?  I'm beginning to think this more of a general issue with running 2 scripts simultaneously as I have also encountered similar issues with PowerShell and Batch when running more than one script simultaneously.  However, I haven't found any other posts from anyone having this issue and I would have thought if Windows (7) had this strict limitation of only being reliable with one script at a time, everyone would know about it.  So I'm not sure if it's as simple as that.

Comment: I did read one post where the user had issues running simultaneous scripts if they created objects, but this user was trying to run many, many simultaneous scripts, not just two.

If I have these lines in both my scripts and run them both at the same time, that should surely be ok?  
  
`set wsnet = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set shellapp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

userprofile = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%")
username = ucase(wsnet.username)`

Comment: I was talking about a separation of elevated and non-elevated actions and run them in a proper order not simultaneously. But your new findings has a good point. And I have a new question: does `verb.DoIt()` exits immediately or it waits until the action will be done? This could be an issue with the shell code when it called too often. What if you'll add a longer pause? Like 5 seconds. Or do some checks to ensure that the library has shown in navigation pane.

Comment: It seems to me that most of what your scripts are doing could be done via Group Policy Preferences. I would recommend using those instead of scripting things like populating the start menu or creating shortcuts.

Comment: I do use group policy but the main script is several thousand lines long and does a lot more than what group policy could achieve.  I'm thinking now that this problem is a restriction with Windows 7 (and probably other versions but i haven't tested those).  I did try running two PowerShell scripts simultaneously from both batch and VBS and I didn't have any problems with either.  The difference is that with PS I'm using native commands instead of creating shell objects with VBS.  I'm thinking that might be the key to the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted some VBS functions (create Windows 7 libraries, populate the start menu and create junction points) into PowerShell scripts and I have not had any problems since.  I run the PowerShell scripts from the main VBScript (which I run elevated).

I don't know why the scripts don't work properly from VBS or Batch but since PowerShell is a far more modern language, it's probably the right way to go and it's a good opportunity to learn more about it.